Proof of utility function for CARA [1(a)] and CRRA equality with power coefficient [1(b)]
I went through the first chapter of Cochrane's Asset pricing and am completely stuck at the first question. I admit that I am an economics idiot, but there is totally no structure to this problem, like how do I even start?
Even the solution set says it is too obvious. I would appreciate any nudge in the right direction or a full solution is VERY MUCH appreciated (although not required).



Taking a look at the definition, seems we are looking for u(c). Take the coefficients of risk aversion, try to integrate them 1 and 2 times respectively and solve for u(c).

To solve (a), define $f(c)=u'(c)$, thus the absolute risk aversion $\alpha$ becomes:
$$\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)}=-\alpha,$$
$$\frac{d}{dc}[\ln(f(c))]=-\alpha,$$
$$d[\ln(f(c))]=-\alpha dc,$$
$$\int d[\ln(f(c))]=\int-\alpha dc,$$
$$\ln(f(c))=-\alpha\int dc,$$
$$\ln(f(c))=-\alpha c+\beta_1,$$
$$f(c)=\beta_2e^{-\alpha c},\;\;\text{with }\beta_2=e^{\beta_1}>0$$
$$f(c)=\beta_2e^{-\alpha c}.$$
We know that $u'(c)=f(c)$ thus
$$\frac{du}{dc}=\beta_2e^{-\alpha c}$$
$$\int du=\int\beta_2e^{-\alpha c}dc$$
$$u(c)=-\frac{\beta_2}{\alpha}e^{-\alpha c}+\beta_3.$$
If $\alpha>0$, which is not stated explicitly but may be derived in the case that $u'(c)>0$ and $u''(c)<0$, then we note that $-e^{-\alpha c}$ represents the same preferences as $u(c)$ since it is an increasing transformation of $u(c)$.
To solve (b), a variation of a similar trick may work.

Thank for the ingenious solution, it is really ridiculous of Cochrane because how are we even expected to come up with a solution like this for an introductory text in asset pricing? I am really flabbergasted.
